# Angular JS Expressions not evaluated in Route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I have a very simple index.html which just has a view inside:

```
<body ng-app="contentApp" ng-controller="contentCtrl">
    <div ng-view></div>
```

Then a script with the routing and a controller

```
var contentApp = angular.module('contentApp', ["ngRoute"]);

contentApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/uebersicht",
        {templateUrl: "uebersicht.html",
         controller: "contentCtrl"}
    )


contentApp.controller('contentCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.test = "Test";
```

So in my index.html file, the controller works just fine. But in my ng-view, where I have the expression

```
{{test}}
```

Nothing happens and the expression is not evaluated.

**EDIT**

The mistake I made was a directive-error in my included file uebersicht.html. So I wrote some pseudocode inside which stopped the whole script to execute.

Comment: Check whether script file is included in index.html.

Comment: Can you show your `ng-view` file?

Comment: @MrNobody it was included as the routing worked fine, the mistake was something different as written above

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have different controller defined for **`uebersicht`**

**DEMO**

```js
var contentApp = angular.module("contentApp", ['ngRoute']);
contentApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/uebersicht", {
      templateUrl: "uebersicht.html",
      controller: "content2Ctrl"
    })
}])
contentApp.controller('contentCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.test = "Test";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="contentApp">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <!--css-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Title of the document -1</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="contentCtrl" class="container">
    <h1>   {{test}}</h1>
    <div ng-view=""></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So that means, I cannot use the same controller for every included file?

Comment: you can use, but no point, it will re initalize the controller again. all the values will be re initialized

Comment: In my Controller there is a script that controls Tabs that are used on multiple included files. Where do I put that script then? Do I really need to copy it for every single controller for every single included file?

Comment: @mstoldt tab means routing? if its common for all the files use service/factory

Comment: Nope Tab means a Tab Bar such as jquery UI. Worked out now

Answer (score 0):

You should use one controller per template. Here is an example

```
var contentApp = angular.module("contentApp", ['ngRoute']);
contentApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/uebersicht", {
      templateUrl: "uebersicht.html",
      controller: "uebersichtCtrl"
    })
}])

contentApp.controller('contentCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.contentModel = "value of content controller";
});

//index.html
<body ng-app="contentApp" ng-controller="contentCtrl">
    {{contentModel}}
    <div ng-view></div>
</body> 

contentApp.controller('uebersichtCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.uebersichtModel = "value of uebersicht controller";
});

// template uebersicht.html
<div ng-app="contentApp" ng-controller="uebersichtCtrl">
     {{uebersichtModel}}
</div>
```

Comment: Not necessarily.. I have a content-Controller with basic stuff, such as a Handler for Tab-Bars or the mobile Menu. That's important for all the templates. But you are right, "special" functions are definitely part of an extra controller.